# Is there a way to create callouts on 2D maps?

Tags: javascript, sdk, arcgis

I'm using `ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript` and was wondering if it's possible to create callout lines from labels to each data point on a 2D map. This is needed because data points are grouped together tightly and overlaying the text over each data point will get congested and difficult to read.

[image]

Seems like this can be done on a [3D map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/visualization-label-callout/) but I can't seem to find anything about being able to do this 2D.